# Command to get paths to jars for ivy-managed dependencies

Tags: ivy

Is there a way to get the paths to the JAR files for ivy-managed dependencies so that a program can be called from the command line and the JAR files are all correctly included in the class path.

Some thing like (for Linux bash and similar scripts):

```
java -cp `ivyget.sh ivy.xml`
```

which could then expand to

```
java -cp "/path/to/first.jar:/path/to/second.jar"
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ivy can be used in a standalone fashion, see the [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/standalone.html). I have included an example below.

While this is a nifty feature I prefer to just use ivy for downloading. If your java program has options (eg -option1 or --option2) then ivy is not capable of properly parsing the command-line.

## Example

The following project is used to manage a database schema using [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/)

```
├── changesets
│   └── scottTiger.xml
├── ivy.xml
├── liquibase.properties
└── liquibase.sh
```

The project is executed by running the shell script

```
./liquibase.sh update
```

### liquibase.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar $HOME/.ant/lib/ivy.jar \
     -error \
     -ivy ivy.xml \
     -main liquibase.integration.commandline.Main \
     -args $@
```

### ivy.xml

The ivy file pulls in the liquibase and H2 database projects as dependencies

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.liquibase" name="liquibase-core" rev="latest.release" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="com.h2database" name="h2" rev="latest.release" conf="default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

### liquibase.properties

Run-time configuration file, where the DB type is set to H2.

```
url=jdbc:h2:./db/scottTiger
driver=org.h2.Driver
username=user
password=pass
changeLogFile=changesets/scottTiger.xml
logLevel=info
```

Comment: Ah, I think I overlooked/misunderstood what the standalone program can do. 
It appears that what I originally wanted can be achieved by running "java -jar ivy.jar ivy.xml -cachepath cpfile" which puts the class path into cpfile and then using e.g.`cat cpfile` to expand this into an cp argument.